# How do I encrypt/decrypt Json Array using node-rsa backend: NodeJS and frontEnd: Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption, node-rsa

I am using node-rsa library in both NodeJS and Angular.
node-rsa: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa

I am trying to encrypt a JSON Array from nodeJS server to be sent Angular where it has to decrypt back to JSON Array, I tried few times with different encoding,no luck. With the below code, no error but array size is 0 when I check at Angular side.

NodeJS:

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa')
...
app.post('/getMembers', (req, res) => {
 const rsaKey = new NodeRSA({
        b: 512
      });
const rsaKey = new NodeRSA({
          b: 512
        });
        rsaKey.importKey(pkey, "pkcs8-public");

   const membersArray = await mongo_groups_collection.aggregate([{...}]).toArray();

   res.status(200).send({
          list: rsaKey.encrypt(membersArray)
        }).end();
});
```

Angular:
Service Snippet:

```
this.getMembersList().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log("Members List received")
      let arrayData:Array<any> = this.secureService.rsaKey.decrypt(data.list);
      console.log("Members decrypted", arrayData)
});
```

In the console, it prints "Members decrypted Uint8Array [] members-crud.service.ts:133  " and the length of arrayData is zero.

Comment: What's the output you are getting when trying - 
console.log("Members decrypted", JSON.parse(arrayData))

Comment: I am trying to get the JSON array back, let me try this and get back